# Azure Log Analytics - Update/Add FunctioAlias to the SavedSearch query

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-log-analytics

I have prepared powershell script for creating Log Analytics "Saved Searches". I am using this cmd-let --> `New-AzOperationalInsightsComputerGroup`. Script works ok, but problem is that using that command I am not able to give the FunctionAlias name, I would like to have possibility to provide that property. I found this cmd-let --> `Set-AzOperationalInsightsSavedSearch`, on MS web site I can find info that we can update SavedSearches using this command let. I have tested this but it doesn't work as expected, I am facing an error, below. I want to add/update FunctionAlias property.
My command:

```
$var = "testalias"
Set-AzOperationalInsightsSavedSearch `
-ResourceGroupName "RGname" `
-WorkspaceName "LogAnalyticsName" `
-SavedSearchId "ID123456" `
-DisplayName "SavedSearcjName"
-FunctionAlias $var
```

Error message:

```
Set-AzOperationalInsightsSavedSearch : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FunctionAlias'.
At line:6 char:1
+ -FunctionAlias $var
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzOperationalInsightsSavedSearch], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.OperationalInsights.SetAzureOperationalInsightsSavedSearchCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `New-AzOperationalInsightsSavedSearch` to create a new saved search with the required parameters.

```
New-AzOperationalInsightsSavedSearch
   [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
   [-WorkspaceName] <String>
   [-SavedSearchId] <String>
   [-DisplayName] <String>
   [[-Version] <Int64>]
   [[-FunctionAlias] <String>]
```

Using this command you can also provide value for `-FunctionAlias`. For more details read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.operationalinsights/new-azoperationalinsightssavedsearch?view=azps-4.4.0).

You can check the created saved searches using the command `Get-AzOperationalInsightsSavedSearch`. You can check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.operationalinsights/get-azoperationalinsightssavedsearch?view=azps-4.4.0).

The command you are using `New-AzOperationalInsightsComputerGroup` is used to create a computer group. Read the details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.operationalinsights/new-azoperationalinsightscomputergroup?view=azps-4.4.0).

Comment: I know that command - New-AzOperationalInsightsSavedSearch. I prepared a script for creating custom computer group, based on the specific Savedsearch in the Solutions targeting blade I can create new custom scope configuration. But I only want to update existing SavedSearch with the FunctionAlias property. But I have just tested suggested cmd-let and have this error massage --> `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FunctionAlias'.`

Comment: Hi, your solution doesn't work, I have just back to my old topic and tested it, doesnt work, I have error message: "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FunctionAlias'"

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that deployments don't override saved searches accidentally, an eTag property should be added in the "savedSearches" resource to override and maintain the idempotency of saved searches. I have made a little change to your PowerShell command as shown below.

```
$var = "testalias"
Set-AzOperationalInsightsSavedSearch `
-ResourceGroupName "RGname" `
-WorkspaceName "LogAnalyticsName" `
-SavedSearchId "ID123456" `
-DisplayName "SavedSearchName"
-FunctionAlias $var -Etag *
```

Comment: this solution does not work, I tested it in the portal, getting error: "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FunctionAlias'".

Comment: I am using command: `Set-AzOperationalInsightsSavedSearch `
-ResourceGroupName "wsus_tests" `
-WorkspaceName "LogAnalytics1506" `
-SavedSearchId "01" `
-DisplayName "PrzemekSS1232" `
-FunctionAlias "PrzemekSS1232" `
-Category "PrzemCategory" `
-Etag "testy"`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a belated answer, but I was struggling with this exact problem today.

The solution, if you want to create this as a 'computer group' is to add the 'tag' parameter: -Tag @{"Group" = "Computer"}

I found 'New-AzOperationalInsightsComputerGroup' to be problematic as it doesn't create the saved search as a function.

So, your code would look like the following:

```
$var = "testalias"
Set-AzOperationalInsightsSavedSearch `
-ResourceGroupName "RGname" `
-WorkspaceName "LogAnalyticsName" `
-SavedSearchId "ID123456" `
-DisplayName "SavedSearcjName" `
-FunctionAlias $var `
-Etag "*" `
-Tag @{"Group" = "Computer"}
```